# MERN application backend is not deploying in render.com

Tags: node.js, reactjs, render.com

I'm trying to deploy my mERN blog application. I've deployed the frontend in netlify. Now I'm trying to deploy the backend in render.com. But Im getting an error while deploying it. The error is shown below,
[image]

I've tried to resolve this by changing the nodemon from dev dependency to actual dependencies. Still nothing works. My package.json of node.js server looks like,
[image]

Any suggestion on this problem would be helpful as I'm new to deploying my mern applications.

Answer (score 1):

modify your package.json

- replace `nodemon src/index.js` to `node src/index.js`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
  }
```

and try deploying again

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue the is because you are giving your log the file from your front end make the root directory in the name of your back-end foleder where your file is stored